# no spaces between consecutive arguments with Clang-Format

Tags: c, clang-format

The C style guide, that I have to use, enforces that there are no spaces between function arguments (or no spaces after comma) in a function call, e.g:

```
foo(a,5.0,"foo");
multi_line_foo(long_var_name,42.0,
               43.0);
```

How can I achieve this with clang-format? None of the spacing related options described in the documentation seems to be suited for this.

Comment: That is a dreadful style guide :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB, I agree. Nonetheless, I have to work with it.